# I cannot build an Expression Tree Node that follows the Open/Close Principle

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, binary-tree, open-closed-principle

I'm trying to define a Tree Node for an expression tree.
I want to define an expression tree operator as class Op {};
Ideally this would be in abstract interface, but if it is, then my class TreeNode { private: Op op;} won't work.
The only solution I can find is to create a Null base class.
There has to be a better approach.
I want to utilize inheritance because if I create new operator types (e.g. unary, binary, ternary, subtraction, division, user defiend) I can just create more and more derived classes to class Op without having to modify any of the base behavior of the other objects. Open/Close Principle.

Below is my current solution.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Op {
public:
    virtual bool is_operand() const {return true;}
    virtual bool is_operator() const {return false;} 
    virtual string get_name() const {return string("fake abstract class");}

    virtual ~Op(){}
};

class Add : public Op {
public:
    bool is_operand() const override {
        return false; 
    }
    bool is_operator() const override {
        return true;
    }
    string get_name() const override{
        string name("add");
        return name; 
    }
};

class IntOperand : public Op {
private:
    int m_value;

public:
    IntOperand() : m_value(0) {}
    IntOperand(int val) : m_value(val) {}

    bool is_operand() const override {
        return true;
    }
    bool is_operator() const override {
        return false; 
    }
    string get_name() const override{
        string res = to_string(m_value);
        return res; 
    }
};

class VarOperand : public Op {
private:
    string m_value;
public:

    VarOperand() : m_value("") {}
    VarOperand(const string& str) : m_value(str) {}

    bool is_operand() const override {
        return true;
    }
    bool is_operator() const override {
        return false; 
    }
    string get_name() const override{
        return m_value;
    }
};

class TreeNode {

public:

    Op m_op; 
    TreeNode * m_left;  //probably should be private. 
    TreeNode * m_right; 
    TreeNode(const Op& op) : m_op(op), m_left(nullptr), m_right(nullptr) {}
};

int main(){
    Add add_op; 
    TreeNode * r0 = new TreeNode(add_op); 
    VarOperand d("d"), c("c"), b("b"), a("a");
    TreeNode dnode(d);
    r0->m_left = &dnode;
    TreeNode add_node0(add_op);  
    r0->m_right = &add_node0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- [Why should I not include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).  It would have been much easier to simply type in the *standard* `#include <string>`.

Comment: `Op m_op;` won't work anyway. If you try and store a derived object in that it'll be sliced. Use smart pointers instead. Not sure what your specific question that can be answered is.

Comment: Search the internet for "Abstract Syntax Tree C++ Example".

Comment: templates (generics) can be an alternative, maybe?

Comment: I tried templates.  TreeNode<Add> works fine, but then TreeNode * m_left, also needs to be TreeNode<Add> * m_left, which I don't want.   You can do syntax weirdness and make something happen, but it is even worse than making a dummy base clase.

Comment: I tried the composition route.  unique_ptr<Op>.  Here, TreeNode would be in charge of creation and destruction of unique_ptr<Op>.  The problem is that you can't do unique_ptr<Abstract>.    I could do a raw pointer,  Op * m_op.  Then, I could call new in the constructor and create m_op (which will call the derived class constructor), but unique_ptr and composition is the more appropriate way to do it.   This has to be a common problem, so I figured there is some natural clean way to do it.   I mean, I can come up with a lot of messy solutions, but I want a clean one.

Comment: I realized that I am trying to make a dynamically defined heterogenous container that is similar in flexibility to a python list or a python dictionary, but in a static language such as C++.  This is actually a very hard problem!  
A C++ "dictionary" is unordered_map<string, int>.  Note here that this is neither dynamically defined nor hetergenous.  At compile time, you know this dictionary will hold string keys and int values.  Also, every key:value pair in this "dictionary" will be string key, value int.   
To make this dynamically defined and hetergenous is very hard.   I'm giving up!